# How can I bundle a background service app with a separate Flutter frontend app to create a single .apk for installation?

Tags: c#, android, .net, flutter, xamarin

I have App 1, written in C# (Xamarin for Android and .NET) that performs background tasks on the device and uses a lot of existing code and dependencies.

I also have new App 2, written in Flutter. This app will be the frontend that speaks to the background service of App 1 to get data and display it.

I want at the end to have 1 .apk to install - the frontend App 2 that starts a C# background service. Is this possible in Android right now?

I understand some platform specific code might be needed in Flutter - maybe a small plugin that provides the interface. Is that right?

I didn't try much, just reading the docs on services and Flutter plugins.